# Tool to make a short youtube video

Tags: video, animation, animation-rendering

I'm a total newbie into developing videos..:) But I would like to create an animated video which is about 5-7 minutes long. The kind of ones we find on youtube.

I did some research to find a tool. I came across online tools like moovly and Animaker. They're easy to use..but their free version has limited features and with the free version you can only have a video length of 2 minutes.

I also stumbled upon the free tool called Blender. But unlike Moovly or Animaker, it seems it requires quite some knowledge in animation to make animation videos in Blender(don't know if I'm right. Just that I feel so..)

Is there a free online tool like Moovly or a software to download like Blender that will help me to easily make an animated video of about 5-7 minutes length which will also allow me to include voiceover and also facilitate adding of some of my custom images (from my desktop) into that animated video..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The kind of ones we find on youtube

Well, youtube is a pretty big place, so you can find a lot of different animations, with different levels of complexity... **really different levels in complexity**.

Even the two online tools you posted are quite different. One is for 2d animations, and the other is more like a video editor. But the most important thing is that those tools have assets, one has animated toons, the other has a library of video clips.

This means that if you use another tool, which I will put a link to, you need to either create your own assets or get them from somewhere else. Video Clips, Music, still photos, cartoons, or even animated cartoons.

Sayed that, two great and free tools are:

[HitFilm Express](https://fxhome.com/hitfilm-express) which is a video editor and a compositor (the compositor is the tool to make basic animations)

And [NHC Express animate](https://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/index.html).

Here is a link to the graphic design forum post I made some days ago, explaining a bit more about them:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136912/free-and-easy-to-use-tool-for-easy-2d-animations/136917#136917

---

**But you can not go as blindly as I feel you are going. You need to define what you really need. Video editing, 2D animation, a slideshow converted into a video..**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Rafael...and thank you so much for the links to the free tools also...:) Being a beginner into this whole subject, I have a doubt...there is also this free online tool called Headliner. Is HitFilm Express a tool like that..?

Comment: On HF you can add text, photos, audio or video. "Like that" is again too board, define specific tasks you need.

Comment: Ok..@Rafael..Thanks...

Comment: Actually what I wanted was to add some images or animations to my voice..